# Using GraphQL in Bazel

Tags: bazel

There's a [Gradle Plugin for GraphQL](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/kotlin/tutorial/01-configure-project) that one can easily integrate in Gradle Projects. As we are moving away from Gradle to Bazel, I am not sure how to migrate a specific module that currently makes use of the Apollo Gradle Plugin.

So imagine that in Gradle the current setup is like this:

```
plugins {
    // ...
    id("com.apollographql.apollo3").version("3.6.2")
}


apollo {
    packageName.set("com.example.rocketreserver")
    srcDir("/src/main/java/com/example/rocketreserver/graphql")
}
```

How would one go about converting this to Bazel?

Is it possible, somehow, to generate a wrapper (maybe custom rule?) on top of the original plugin and use it in Bazel, or a new plugin from scratch should be written in this case?

Any input is highly appreciated.

Comment: did you end up figuring out the solution? i am in the same boat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no Bazel equivalent for the Apollo Gradle plugin, however, building
one for Bazel is pretty straightforward.

#### How the Gradle Apollo plugin works

If we check the [sources of the Apollo Gradle plugin](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-kotlin/blob/main/libraries/apollo-gradle-plugin-external/src/main/kotlin/com/apollographql/apollo3/gradle/internal/ApolloGenerateSourcesTask.kt#L382),
we notice that the gradle plugin is nothing but a facade
in front of the [apollo-compiler](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-kotlin/tree/main/libraries/apollo-compiler) library.
`apollo-compiler` is a separate library responsible for the actual code generation, and this library is decoupled from the gradle plugin implementation.

To trigger code generation directly via `apollo-compiler`
one can use:

```kotlin
import java.io.File

val outputDir = File("apollo")
val queryFile = File("queries.graphql")
val schemaFile = File("schema.graphqls")
val testDir = File("apolloTest")
val packageName = "com.example"

val options = Options(
    setOf(queryFile),
    schemaFile,
    outputDir,
    testDir,
    packageName
)

ApolloCompiler.write(options)
```

The generated sources will be placed in a directory defined by `outputDir` in a package defined by `packageName`.

#### Building a Bazel rule that triggers the code generation

With the above in place we can now [create a Bazel rule](https://github.com/vgrec/bazel-graphql-poc/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/compiler/rules.bzl) that takes as input the `schema` and `.graphql` files
and produces as output the generated source code. For convenience, the generated
source code is zipped into a source jar, and this source jar becomes the target's output
which other rules can depend on.